# Linear Algebra: Matrix/Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question: Assume that A is a symmetric matrix. Show that if m > 0 and $A^m$ = I, then $A^2$ = I.

Can I get some insights on how to approach this question. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not true. Are you talking about a $2\times 2$ matrix?

Comment: Please avoid " I have zero idea" questions. Try to find out what you can use from your lecture. Another counterexample is $A={\rm diag}(i,i)$ with $A^4=I$ but $A^2=-I\neq I$.

Comment: If $A$ has real entries the conclusion is true, as the matrix is diagonalizable and its eigenvales can be equal $\pm 1.$

Comment: @drago I assume $A$ is supposed to have real entries. Can you use the fact that (real) symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable with real eigenvalues?